# Custom logger with time stamp in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have lots of code on a project with print statements and wanted to make a quick a dirty logger of these print statements and decided to go the custom route.  I managed to put together a logger that prints both to the terminal and to a file (with the help of this site), but now I want to add a simple time stamp to each statement and I am running into a weird issue.

Here is my logging class.

```
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.terminal = stream
        self.log = open("test.log", 'a')

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.flush()
        self.terminal.write(self.stamp() + message)
        self.log.write(self.stamp() + message)

    def stamp(self):
        d = datetime.today()
        string = d.strftime("[%H:%M:%S] ")
        return string
```

Notice the stamp method that I then attempt to use in the write method.

When running the following two lines I get an unexpected output:

```
sys.stdout = Logger(sys.stdout)
print("Hello World!")
```

Output:

```
[11:10:47] Hello World![11:10:47]
```

This what the output also looks in the log file, however, I see no reason why the string that I am adding appends to the end.  Can someone help me here?

**UPDATE**
See answer below.  However, for quicker reference the issue is using "print()" in general; replace it with sys.stdout.write after assigning the variable.

Also use "logging" for long-term/larger projects right off the bat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It calls the `.write()` method of your stream twice because in cpython `print` calls the stream `.write()` method twice. The first time is with the object, and the second time it writes a newline character. For example look at [line 138 in the `pprint` module in cpython v3.5.2](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.2/Lib/pprint.py#l138)

```
def pprint(self, object):
    self._format(object, self._stream, 0, 0, {}, 0)
    self._stream.write("\n")  # <- write() called again!
```

You can test this out:

```
>>> from my_logger import Logger  # my_logger.py has your Logger class
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout = Logger(stream=sys.stdout)
>>> sys.stdout.write('hi\n')
[14:05:32] hi
```

You can replace `print(<blah>)` everywhere in your code using [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

```
$ for mymodule in *.py; do
> sed -i -E "s/print\((.+)\)/LOGGER.debug(\1)/" $mymodule
> done
```

Check out [Python's Logging builtin module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html). It has pretty comprehensive logging including inclusion of a timestamp in all messages format.

```
import logging
FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(message)s'
DATEFMT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, datefmt=DATEFMT)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.debug('message: %s', 'message')
```

This outputs `2016-07-29 11:44:20 message: message` to `stdout`. There are also handlers to send output to files. There is a [basic tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial), an [advanced tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial) and a [cookbook of common logging recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook).

There is an example of using [simultaneous file and console loggers](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-logging-in-multiple-modules) in the cookbook.

```
import logging

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)  # get logger named for this module
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # set logger level to debug

# create formatter
LOG_DATEFMT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
LOG_FORMAT = ('\n[%(levelname)s/%(name)s:%(lineno)d] %(asctime)s ' +
              '(%(processName)s/%(threadName)s)\n> %(message)s')
FORMATTER = logging.Formatter(LOG_FORMAT, datefmt=LOG_DATEFMT)

CH = logging.StreamHandler()  # create console handler
CH.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # set handler level to debug
CH.setFormatter(FORMATTER)  # add formatter to ch
LOGGER.addHandler(CH)  # add console handler to logger

FH = logging.FileHandler('myapp.log')  # create file handler
FH.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # set handler level to debug
FH.setFormatter(FORMATTER)  # add formatter to fh
LOGGER.addHandler(FH)  # add file handler to logger

LOGGER.debug('test: %s', 'hi')
```

This outputs:

```
[DEBUG/__main__:22] 2016-07-29 12:20:45 (MainProcess/MainThread)
> test: hi
```

to both console and file `myapp.log` simultaneously.

Comment: I am aware that Python has builtin logging capability.  Currently my project is in a freeze point so I can't make any major changes I only want quick and dirty fixes.  Until that time that I can implement a better logger with the aforementioned module, I want to only fix my current issue, if possible.  Unless "logging" can output regular print statements to both stdout and a file then this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Python loggers can have multiple handlers, _ie_: both console and file, simultaneously. IMHO I wouldn't consider using the Python builtin logging module a _major change_. IMO it is easy to use and implement quickly. And there are many advantages - for example, you can turn it on/off easily. IMO making a custom logger from scratch is a much larger challenge. :)

Comment: OK! You got me with the how detailed that output is.  However, I am still curious as to why my previous implementation would do such a strange thing.

Comment: @Tristan see edits to my answer - if you can unfreeze your code, maybe you can replace `print(<blah>)` with `LOGGER.debug(<blah>)` using `sed` in a `for` bash loop? otherwise, I think your hack is pretty cool!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, either way I have to replace print.  I can just fork my project and roll back commits.  People are actively using a GUI I built but there is downtime to change it.  I just don't want to break it; almost did that once already after changing lots of lines of code.

Comment: Good luck! If you're open to suggestions, use [Git](https://git-scm.com/), consider adding [unit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) with either [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [py.test](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) and maybe way too late for you this time, but consider deploying your UI in a web browser using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) - the main advantage being if you serve your app from either inside your network or in the cloud, updating has zero impact to end users. And HTML can do anything Qt can do. Try [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use newline character.

```
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.terminal = stream
        self.log = open("test.log", 'a')

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.flush()
        self.terminal.write(self.stamp() + message + "\n")
        self.log.write(self.stamp() + message + "\n")

    def stamp(self):
        d = datetime.today()
        string = d.strftime("[%H:%M:%S] ")
        return string
```

Anyway, using built-in logging module will be better.